# Error installing Twisted for Python

Tags: python, twisted, failed-installation

I tried installing twisted on an Ubuntu VM like this:

pip install twisted

It downloads and starts installation, but gets this error:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-SQhfJz/twisted/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ItHrMV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-SQhfJz/twisted
```

I'm not a real programmer, just a hobbyist, so this is way over my head. Googling it showed it needs python-dev and build-essential. I installed both of those, but installing twisted still got the same error as before.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you install the dev packages for the correct version of Python?  Run ``python --version`` if the version is ``3.x.x`` then you might have to use install ``python3-dev`` and then ``pip3 install twisted``. FYI Twisted hasn't been fully ported to Python 3.

Comment: Thanks, notorious. My version is 2.7.3, so I presume the other packages were the right ones.

Answer (score 15):

As a maintainer of Twisted, I'm sorry you're having a bad experience installing it.  It's not your fault for being a hobbyist - it should just work :-).

It would be helpful if you could include more complete logs when reporting an installation error.  Presumably there is some other stuff that `pip` tried to do.  For example, when I tried to reproduce this error, I saw something similar, but right above it it said

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted': Permission denied
```

which was the real bug.  Is that what your installation attempt said?  If so, then you have two options:

1. You installed `build-essential` and `python-dev`.  If you have the ability to `apt-get install` stuff, perhaps consider just `apt-get install python-twisted`?  This will install an older version, but since it's supported by your operating system vendor it's almost guaranteed to work.
2. You can install into a [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).  Installing into a virtualenv isolates packages from your system Python environment and reduces the number of things that can go wrong.  One thing that can popularly go wrong is that `pip install twisted` by itself will try to install into your system's Python package manager, which is what the error I pasted above means.  You can then do:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
   $ virtualenv my-fun-env
   $ source my-fun-env/bin/activate
   (my-fun-env)$ pip install twisted
   ```

   this will install Twisted inside a virtual environment only, which you can easily throw away and re-create to experiment with new versions of Twisted, so you don't have to make changes to your whole system to try things out.
3. *Don't* do this: one popular way to "fix" this problem is to do `sudo pip install ...`.  This may superficially appear to work, but it also carries the risk of breaking your computer, and you *really* shouldn't do it unless you can easily reinstall your operating system to fix it.  If another answerer suggests this, ignore them.  Use one of my other two proposed fixes :).

Comment: Glyph, thanks so much for the detailed help! Um, when I saw you guessed correctly about "error: could not create.. Permission denied," I impulsively ran the command again with sudo... forgetting that was exactly what you said not to do. It said "Successfully installed twisted-15.2.1," so that's at least superficially a good sign. If the VM breaks, well, that'll teach me to follow directions slowly and methodically next time.

Comment: Well, you'll have a working Twisted - for now :).  The problems come later when you need to apply security updates or install a package into apt that depends on Twisted.  So as long as it's a VM that you can easily re-create, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for using Twisted!

Comment: If you're using Python3 on Ubuntu make sure to `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`.

Answer (score 8):

I have fixed it by installing the folowing packages

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
```